# postgres sql to extract year-month

Tags: sql, postgresql

Have a table  with a column like this:

```
   first_day_month         
   01/07/2020    
   01/07/2020    
   01/08/2020    
   01/09/2020   
  .......
```

Need to create a column like year-month,
Tried `to_char(first_day_month, 'MM/YYYY')` but got an error:

```
Error running query: INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Failed to tokenize string [M] at offset [0]
```

Tried

```
concat(extract(year from first_day_month),'-',extract(month from first_day_month) ) as month,
```

with an error:

```
Error running query: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 2:1: Unexpected parameters (bigint, varchar(1), bigint) for function concat. Expected: concat(array(E), E) E, concat(E, array(E)) E, concat(array(E)) E, concat(varchar)
```

Also tried date_parse but didn't get it right, any idea?
Thanks

Comment: what's column's data type?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The output you pasted above in your comment seems wrong.  It should be `07/2020`, as the input is 1st July 2020.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `TO_DATE` first, to convert the column to a proper date.  Then use `TO_CHAR` to format as you want:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(first_day_month, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY') AS my
FROM yourTable;
```

Note that in this case since the text month year you want is actually just the right substring, you could also directly use `RIGHT` here:

```
SELECT RIGHT(first_day_month, 7)
FROM yourTable;
```

Finally, note that `YYYY/MM` would generally be a better format to use, as it sorts properly.  So perhaps consider using this version:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(first_day_month, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YYYY/MM') AS ym
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data doesn't seem to be of `DATE` type, might be string, then need to convert to `DATE` type first and format display style as desired pattern :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(first_day_month::DATE,'MM/YYYY') AS first_day_month
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=30d346ab7941cabf1f3db49574f777a1)</kbd>